# Improving performance of ArcGIS Pro while working on a network?

Tags: arcgis-pro, performance

As many others, I'm working from home at the moment. ArcGIS Pro is running on my local machine with access to remote file servers through a VPN. VPN is at times running quite slow due to everyone working from home and thus every operation in ArcGIS Pro, like adding data, geoprocessing and exporting data, is quite slow. Are there any tricks to speed up ArcGIS Pro on a slow network? E.g. increasing cache size if possible? Using a local scratch gdb? I can't copy files over to a local database cause colleagues also have to be able to work on the same projects and with the same geodatabases.

Comment: File geodatabase isn't safe for multiple writers anyway, so there isn't much to be gained from processing through a VPN.  Copy what you can locally. You certainly don't want the project geodatabase at the long end of a busy, slow chain of network hops.

Answer (score 5):

- The best option is to leave a computer on physically on the network you're working on, and then Remote Desktop into the computer itself. That way the data isn't actually moving over the internet, which even under more ideal conditions I've found terribly slow.  Rather, just the image of what is on the screen is moving over the internet, which is far less burdensome. The computer physically on the network does all the work, and you just see an image of what is happening.
- Another option as Vince says is to copy as much as you can locally.
- Finally, we've found ArcMap to be faster than ArcGIS Pro over a VPN,
  so you might switch up the software you're using if you can...

Answer (score 1):

No question the best option is to use remote desktop, but in addition I have found two things that helped in some siutations:

1. Turn of indexing. Settings -> Options -> Indexing -> Check radio button "Don't create index"
2. Publish a feature server webservice through Portal then work with the data through the web service. Add data -> Data from Path -> Enter the URL of the feature web service. The problem with this approach is if you have editor tracking turned on, it's not the best for that.